# fwrite problem, cannot write in binary file!

Tags: c, integer, binaryfiles, fwrite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C Programming - File - fwrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282823/c-programming-file-fwrite)

include....
>

```
int main(void)
{

  FILE *Archivo;
  int proba=5;

  Archivo=fopen("md3.dat", "ab+");
  fwrite(&proba, sizeof(int), 1, Archivo);
  fclose(Archivo);
  printf("Bye!\n\n");
}
```

I just can't print any number on the binary fila md3.dat, please help!

Comment: What happens when you try the above code?

Comment: An issue I can see at first glance: You do not check if fopen() succeeded by comparing the Archivo pointer with NULL.

Comment: -1 for dupe. OP already asked the same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282823/c-programming-file-fwrite/4282837#4282837)

Comment: @SiegeX: using a different username too...

Answer (score 3):

I think OP is expecting `fwrite` to behave as `fprintf` and write an ASCII decimal string the the file, then getting confused when the output is the bytes `5,0,0,0` (all non-printable characters) which probably shows up blank when opening it in an editor or using `cat` to print it to the terminal (or `type` on DOS).

If you want to write text, use `fprintf`.

Comment: then how do I know that the 5 is written into the binary if it shows blank when opening?? Im just an amateur...

Comment: @Jujitsu2 - Check the file size in your shell. It should be 4 bytes (assuming `sizeof(int)` is 4 on your system and you've only written one `int` to the file). If you're on Linux or OS X, use the `xxd` command to check the binary contents - it should probably be the 4 bytes 5, 0, 0, and 0.

Comment: Agreed, this is [exactly what I offered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282823/c-programming-file-fwrite/4290646#4290646) the last time the OP asked this question.

Comment: THANK YOU! THIS REEEEALLY HELPED US

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Archivo = fopen("md3.sat", "wb+");
fseek(Archivo, 0, SEEK_END);
fwrite(&proba, sizeof(int), 1, Archivo);
```

This should write your `int` value at the end of the file. Also, you should check for function return values. Remember: **you are in C!!**.

```
int written;
Archivo = fopen("md3.sat", "wb+");
if (Archivo != NULL) {
    fseek(Archivo, 0, SEEK_END);
    written = fwrite(&proba, sizeof(int), 1, Archivo);
    printf("%d int values written!\n", written);
}
```

Comment: why there should be a difference? (except different file extensions)

Comment: There's a huge difference: File Open Mode `ab+` vs. `wb+`.

Comment: @Vlad, The file open mode is also different.

Comment: @Pablo, @Anil: Yes, but you seek to the file end, so IMHO there should be none.

Comment: But your code just uses "wb+" and then seeks to the end. Isn't that the same as "ab+"?

Comment: @Vlad: he/she is trying to write to the end of file, because he/she's using `a` (append) open mode.

Comment: i tried both of them, none of them worked :s

Comment: @Jujitsu2: do you get the file open? What does the program print?

Comment: @Pablo: and your code does the same, so there should be no difference, right?

Comment: it doesn't print ANYTHING... it sucks :s

Comment: @Jujutsu2: Then your file is not opening properly. `fopen` call is the one failing. Are you sure the file exists? Do you have write permissions on it?

Comment: yes we have, and the file creates itself with the function fopen. try it yourself @Pablo